# I can't get data in fragment By Using Bundle()

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

in recycler view when click item work and clicked and the fragment open successfully but the date can't send or error is show in fragment when call the date in Bundle()

**//This Code In RecyclerView**

```
    holder.setItemClickListener(object:IItemClickListenerQuran{
        override fun clickedItem(view: View, position: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Click At Quran Sora: " + items[position].name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("SoraName", items[position].name)

            val fragment = SoraDetailsFragment()
            val activity = view.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_Fragment_Continer, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

**//This Code In Fragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view:View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sora_details, container, false)

    val args = arguments
    val SoraName = args!!.getString("SoraName")
    Log.d("receiver", "SoraName: " + SoraName);

    return view
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating bundle . But you didn't bind the bundle as arguments.
Try adding this line.

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("SoraName", items[position].name)
val fragment = SoraDetailsFragment()
fragment.arguments = bundle // This is where bundle is attached to fragment as arguments
```

Comment: He is, thank you, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the data using safeArg, here is the approach
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putBoolean("SoraName", items[position].name)
val fragment = SoraDetailsFragment()
fragment.setArguments(bundle)

val activity = view.context as AppCompatActivity
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_Fragment_Continer, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

Comment: He is, thank you, I didn't notice that